# How to call a method of class with in a module from another class in ruby

Tags: ruby, module

How to call a method of a class which exist in a module. For e.g

```
class Earth
    def country
       puts " Earth Country"
    end
end

module Testing
    class World < Earth
        def country
            puts "country method from module Testing and class World"
        end
    end
    def country
        puts "country method from module Testing"
    end
end
puts Testing::World.new.country

class Country
 include Testing

    def country
        puts "country method from Country Class"
    end
end
puts Country.new.country
```

Now how can I call a `World` class country method from `Country` class. Need specific answer with explanation. I know I can call using `Testing::World.new.country` but then whats the purpose of including module.

Also how to call a module `Testing` country method from `Country` class and from outside. Please clear the concept of calling `Earth` class country method from `Country` class. I am totally confused need proper explanation between `module` and `class`.

Comment: Is this a homework question?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes [dax](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2128691/dax) you can think so. But don't you guys help a beginner of ruby module in understanding this problem?

Comment: I think you're likely to get more help of better quality if you're honest about what you're asking (and if the 'why' is because it's your homework) and what you've done on your own before asking here.   Including things like 'Need specific answer with explanation.' is inviting trolls and downvotes.

Comment: Just as a note none of these are class methods. These are instance methods. I am always glad to help a new comer but I think some due diligence on your part to at least understand the basics is a good idea. But if you must call the `World` instance method from country you would use `World.new.country`